# SystemVerilog over vcs saving simulation state and rewinding

Tags: system-verilog, synopsys-vcs

I am running a testbench using systemverilog over OVM using vcs.
I want to save my simulation after some reset phase and then return to it later on in the test, or/and from another testbench. Is this possible using systemverilog cmds?

Alternatively is there a way to do this using vcs cmds?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is `$save` command in vcs, to save the session. That command needs to be placed in the design itself.

In your case you can do something like this.

```
initial
begin
      reset = 1'b1; // Asserting Reset
  #10 reset = 1'b0; // Deasserting Reset
      $save ("reset_state.chk");
  //  Post reset data
end
```

This will save the reset state in `reset_state.chk` file.

Comment: So how would I do that from a systemverilog class (OVM sequence).
Or do I have to use initial begin?

Comment: Yes one way is to use $save in program/module. To use save restore mechanism from class, I believe, you may need to refer the VCS user guide.